# How to adjust intervals on axis in power bi charts

Tags: powerbi

I'm building a power bi dashboard. One question is that can I adjust the axis interval. As shown below, the x-axis represents year, the default interval is 5 years. Is it possible to change it to 2 or 1 year? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can either make the chart wider, which will add ticks to the x-axis, or you could change the type of the x-axis from continuous to categorical. But there are no further options than these.

[image]